# Flowplayer change current video with links

Tags: javascript, html, flowplayer

I have a flowplayer at the top of my page and then a list of links underneath that link to different videos.

Is it possible to load the new video into the player from the links?

Comment: changing the "src" value dynamically using JavaScript helped me in many other players in HTML. I believe this should work the same.

Comment: Is it possible to change both sources? Both the mp4 and the webm src?

Are there any online examples of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flowplayer has an extensive [Javascript API](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html) that allows you to change many aspects of the `player` object, including the current video playing.

In addition, in order to use the links for this purpose, you can bind an event handler to the links, that will load the `href` attribute of the link into the `player` object.

For example, with jQuery you can do this:

```
$('.video_link').on('click', function() {
    $('#video_player').setClip($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to change both src?

    <video>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.website.com/video.mp4"/>
      <source type="video/webm" src="http://www.website.com/video.webm"/>
    </video>